# quickly compare values in a text file

Tags: bash, shell-script, file-comparison

I have a text file with 2 columns first column is a name, second colomn is an time value. like:

```
cat  34M
dog  34M
fish 12M
ant  34M
```

I need to compare the second colomn for the same values, and if 1 is different that the rest I want to flag the entry.
So in this case, fish should be flagged because it is different from the rest. The file is dynamic and changes by a for loop on a folder bases, so My script should run the compare in a for loop.

```
for FOLDER in is find ${DIR}/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name values.txt`; do
<something to flag the 'odd' value>
done
```

I guess I should sort on second colomn first and then take the first (highest) value as lead marker to compare to. The file could contain more then 1 'odd' values. The file can contain between 2 and 500 entries.
I could do something with a sub script or with awk, but I have no clue where to start.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: "I should sort on second colomn first and then take the first (highest) value as lead marker to compare to" -  Are the flaggable values always lower than the common ones?

Comment: What if there are 100 `34M` values and 10 `12M` values? Should the `12M` entries be flagged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values fit in memory, which your 'up to 500' should, and depending on exactly what you want, **`awk` can probably do it** in one pass and (at least mostly) in one process.

To list any and all value(s) that occur once, in arbitrary order if more than one:

```
awk '!n[$2++]{a[$2]=$1} END{for(v in n)if(n[v]==1)print a[v],v}'
# can pipe output to a suitable sort if you want a specific order
# or for GNU awk 4, you can get several non-arbitrary orders
# (less than GNU sort) using PROCINFO["sorted_in"] see the manual
```

To list one value that occurs once, if there is at least one:

```
awk '!n[$2++]{a[$2]=$1} END{for(v in n)if(n[v]==1){print a[v],v;exit}}'
```

To list one value that occurs once and otherwise indicate there are none:

```
awk '!n[$2++]{a[$2]=$1} END{for(v in n)if(n[v]==1){print a[v],v;exit};print "no unique entry"}'
```

Comment: This is a good basis from where I started to build my script around. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

```
awk -v std="$( awk '{print $2}' file.txt | \
    sort | \
    uniq -c | \
    sort -rn | \
    awk 'NR==1 {print $2; exit}' )" '$2!=std' file.txt
```

The long command inside `$(...)` determines the most common time value, while the outer `awk` command picks all entries with different values in the second column.  The script doesn't take into account possible time "aliases", such as `1M = 60S` etc., it just handles `12M` and `34M` as strings.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using diff? If your first column matches in both files, this tool will fit perfectly. Otherwise you can simply get the second column and then compare it with diff. You can use diff in your script as well.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html

Comment: There's only one file.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work as expected. Thanks for the tip though!.